# How to simplify if statement using Optional.ofNullable()

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

How can I simplify the code below using Optional.ofNullable(), lambda expression and so on:

```
private String getStudentSection(Student student){
    String section = "PRIMARY";
    if(student != null){
        int std = student.getStandard();
        if(std > 5){
            section = "SECONDARY";
        }
    }
    return section;
}
```

I have tried to do the following:

Using `Optional.ofNullable(student)` then map and then filter expressions but I get stuck on how to return the section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
String section = "PRIMARY";
Optional.ofNullable(student)
        .map( i -> (i.getStandard() > 5) ? "SECONDARY" : section )
        .orElse(section);
```